# How can I use pg_search capabilities from ActiveAdmin filters?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, activeadmin, ransack, pg-search

I am using ActiveAdmin (the latest version) for an interface to my data. I am looking to implement some full-text search functionality and I'd like to try to use pg_search rather than SOLR or something like that.

I see that pg_search creates scopes on the model to enable searching.

How can I get ActiveAdmin to call these scopes with user-supplied values via the filter interface on the index page for the resource?

I see how to use scopes that don't take any arguments in ActiveAdmin, but now how to use scopes via the filter interface.

Comment: That's not possible. There are some hacks, but they should not be used.

Comment: I'd take a hack over nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using pg_search to create a custom scope on the model, then I use ransack to [configure those scopes](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/288), then I can use the filter in AA.

I think this doesn't have any of the downsides Timo is referring to.

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/288#issuecomment-39053547) to the example code on the mentioned Github issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, but it is something that should be used with caution, it brings other problems, while it is not the right way to use ransack!

http://nikhgupta.com/code/activeadmin/custom-filters-using-ransacker-in-activeadmin-interfaces/